# Does this Hamiltonian have correct dimensions?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-spin, units, hamiltonian, dimensional-analysis

In a homework problem, I was given a Hamiltonian for the interaction of two spin $1$ particles:

$$H = a\vec{S}_1\cdot\vec{S}_2 + b\bigl(\vec{S}_1\cdot\vec{S}_2\bigr)^2$$
where $\vec{S}_i$ are both spin-1 operators, and $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$.

I got that eigenvalues of $\vec{S}_1\cdot\vec{S}_2$ are proportional to $\hbar^2$, so the energies that this Hamiltonian yields are a linear combination of $\hbar^2$ and $\hbar^4$, which can not be true, because the dimensions are not compatible.

If they wrote $\vec{\sigma}_i$ or $\frac{\vec{S}_i}{\hbar}$ instead of $\vec{S}_i$, things would make more sense, but that's not the case.

Is there really a problem, of am I missing something?

Comment: hint: what are the dimensions of $a,b$?

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ are dimensionless, there is a problem, so, obviously they can't be.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform You mean "what are the *dimensions* of $a$ and $b$", right?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform in my problem, these are just numbers. $1$ and $\frac 1 3$. Do I have to assume that they mean $1$ and $\frac 1 3$ have the correct dimensions to make sense of this?

Comment: This way I can make the dimensions compatible, but how do I know what $are$ the dimensions? A hamiltonian doesn't necesserily have an energy dimension...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a problem. Based on the information you've given, the terms have incompatible dimensions, $\hbar^2$ and $\hbar^4$ respectively, as you concluded. Normally, I would expect $a$ and $b$ to have appropriate units to make everything work out, but if the problem really says $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ as you said, then they are unitless and that makes the expression inconsistent.

I suppose it's possible that they are using $\vec{S}_i$ to mean $\vec{\sigma}_i$ or $\vec{\sigma}_i/2$ or some such thing, but that would be unusual, and if so it should be stated somewhere in the context in which the problem was given.

Comment: I asked the teacher, and he said it is assumed we are working at a system where hbar=1. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should take $\vec{S_i}$ to have the usual units of angular momentum. Then, put in the right units for $a$ and $b$ in order to recover the units of energy for $H$ of $\hbar^2$ and $\hbar^4$.